# Why does coverity complain when using calloc with unsigned int

Tags: c, calloc, coverity

I have the following:

```
static unsigned int *tick = NULL;
...
 if (tick == NULL)
     tick = calloc(MAX_PORT,sizeof(unsigned int));
...
```

which functionally works as expected but coverity complains with:
**Parse warning (PW.INCOMPATIBLE_ASSIGNMENT_OPERANDS)
1. incompatible_assignment_operands: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned int *"** 
and  I don't entirely understand why

Comment: What is `MAX_PORT` ?

Comment: What is `MAX_PORT`?  Where is `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Just guessing here: You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`? It's not the `unsigned int` it complains about, but the assignment to `tick`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude correct, I added it now.

Comment: Why are you programming in C90 in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message suggests that Coverity thinks that `calloc` returns an `int`, 
which can happen if you haven't included `stdlib.h` (for `calloc)` in the older C.
But this is not allowed in modern C (i.e., no implicit declarations allowed in C99 and above).

Comment: "Not allowed" might be better written as "non-conforming".  Every C compiler I work with *allows* undeclared functions to be called, using the semantics C90 brought forward from K&R C.  Such code indeed does not conform to the C99 or C2011 standard, but there is no requirement that it be rejected.

Comment: I now included stdlib.h, I'll see if it disappears. Thanks!

Comment: The real question though, is how this compiled without any form of compiler messages. Assignment from `int` to `unsigned int*` is not valid C. Never been.

Answer (score 1):

> "... which functionally works as expected"

No, this code cannot compile on any version of C, new or old.

In older versions of C called C90, you could forget about including `stdlib.h` and the compiler would then treat `calloc` as a function returning `int`, rather than `void*`. This is what the static analyser is on about. But the code should not even compile, because it would have resulted in a diagnostic even on a C90 compiler - you cannot assign `int` to an `unsigned int*`. It has never been valid C.

In standard C, the code wouldn't even get that far, because the compiler would tell you it has no idea what the identifier `calloc` is.

All of this suggests that your compiler is 1) old and 2) non-compliant.

Comment: I would guess that you are using an older version of the gcc compiler, which defaults to "crap mode", aka gnu90. In gnu90, they allow C standard constraint violations, because: crap.

Comment: I'm using `diab` from WindRiver, not GCC.

Comment: @cerr Ok, you might want to report a bug to them and/or get a better compiler. `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` gives "error: implicit declaration of function 'calloc'". gcc in dinosaur mode `gcc -std=c90 -pedantic-errors` or in crap mode `gcc -pedantic-errors` say the same, but this time only a warning, not an error. gcc dinosaur & crap both fail to give a diagnostic about the constraint violation. I only get that when I provoke it: `tick = (int)calloc(...`

Comment: @cerr: If the `diab` compiler didn't complain, then you need to get a better compiler.  (If it complained but you didn't fix its complaint, then you're at fault; compilers do not generate warnings to annoy — they generate them because they're confident you didn't mean what you wrote.  At this stage of your career, and for the next thirty-plus years, accept that the compiler knows more about C than you do.)  These days, it isn't clear you can compile GCC with `diab`; it requires a fairly competent modern C++ compiler to bootstrap the compilation of GCC.